# в чем отличие Primary key по одному или нескольким полям?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

В чем заключается разница в создании Primary key по одному полю или по нескольким полям? И на что это будет влиять? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас задан РК по 1 полю, то у вас будет только это поле проверяться на уникальность при создании новой записи, если РК будет на несколько полей, то при создании записи или редактировании будет проверять на уникальность все поля что состоят в РК.

Думаю доступно объяснил.

Comment: То что вы описали, легко достичь созданием лишь только `unique constraint`.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю ваш первый вопрос уже частично содержит в себе ответ.
Стоит только добавить что в mysql можно создать индекс по нескольким полям при этом в запросе указывать не все поля(только первые в индексе) и тогда индекс также будет использоваться

На что влияет?:

- На размер индекса
- Скорость вставки/обновления (из за проверки на уникальность
  нескольких полей)
- Сортировку

Хорошим примером primary key по двум столбцам является связующая таблица отношения "многие ко многим". [book_id|author_id]

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю, о какой разнице Вы желаете получить информацию, но полагаю, что наиболее правильным будет ответ "Никакой разницы нет".

Я навскидку вижу только 2 аспекта, о которых имеет смысл вспомнить, 2 момента, которые появляются дополнительно при составном ПК.

Первый - это особенность использования автоинкремента в составном ПК - он может быть как первым полем в выражении ПК, так и вторым. В последнем случае у него достаточно забавное поведение - вроде бы и функциональное, но настолько потенциально проблемное в многопользовательской среде, что даже не знаю, это больше благо или проблема.

Ну и второй - это возможность ссылочной целостности на такой ПК не по полному значению ключа, а по префиксному значению. Впрочем, полезность этой фичи мне представляется несколько сомнительной.